# How do the US President's and Secretary of Defense's power to deploy troops differ?

Tags: united-states, president, military, cabinet

In the May 17, 2022 Late Night with Stephen Colbert clip [Mark Esper's Loyalty To The Constitution Got Him Fired From The T**** Administration](https://youtu.be/qPneveBZhzM?t=178) in a segment where he recounted several instances of people close to the US president recommending he deploy troops in non-military situations, he said:

> ...but then as we got closer in the final days leading up to the election, I think it was the last Friday in October I had to call my head of the National Guard in and the Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff and have this private discussion and say "listen, in the days... on the election day and the days following it if you get any type of call from The White House notify me immediately so I can intercede if that's what it took to prevent anything bad from happening, if you will.

and soon after:

> **That's why the position of Secretary of Defense is so important; because the only two people in the United States that can deploy troops are the president, and the secretary of defense.** So it was critical for me to be in that position to be the *circuit breaker* in case somebody wanted to do something, whether it was deploy troops to suppress protesters or deploy troops to grab a ballot box as the case may be.

Note that Esper is advertising his new book in this segment and this is a late night comedy show not a news cast, but considering the source [Mark Esper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Esper)'s military training and background we can assume it to be at least a credible viewpoint.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** How do the US President's and Secretary of Defense's power to deploy troops differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constitution places all executive power in the hands of the President, and makes the President commander in chief

> Article II
>
> The executive Power shall be vested in a President of the United States of America. ... The President shall be Commander in Chief of the Army and Navy of the United States, and of the Militia of the several States...

The Secretary of State for Defense in not mentioned in the Constitution, it is a post created by Congress and only has such powers granted by Congress and the President.

> The Secretary is the principal assistant to the President in all matters relating to the Department of Defense. Subject to the direction of the President and to this title and section 2 of the National Security Act of 1947 (50 U.S.C. 3002) he has authority, direction, and control over the Department of Defense.([10 U.S. Code § 113](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/10/113))

The notion of "Deploy troops" is vague, and in a sense every Corporal has the power to deploy the soldiers under their command. However the powers granted by the President to the Secretary of Defense to deploy troops are wide-ranging.  The Secretary is subject only to the orders of the President in matters relating to the operation and administration of all branches of the Military.

So, "How do the US President's and Secretary of Defense's power to deploy troops differ?" The president derives his power from the constitution. The Defense secretary derives his power from the President (and Congress). The President can overrule the Defense secretary. The Defense secretary can't overrule the President.

Comment: "The notion of "Deploy troops" is vague..." I'm having a hard time believing that what sounds to be pretty not-vague from a West Point graduate is truly so vague, but maybe so. In the mean time: Oh, the [I have an article two that says I can do whatever I want](https://youtu.be/sl_gO3uOds8) article II? :-)

Comment: Deploy means order (troops) to a certain place.  If a Sergent orders a corporal to take a detail and dig latrines and the corporal orders two private soldiers to dig and two to carry, then the corporal has "deployed troops".  But of course the corporal doesn't have the general power to deploy troops, except that which given to him/her through the chain of command.  The same is true of the Defense secretary it is just that the secretary is a lot closer to to the top of that chain.

Comment: and you're certain that the 23rd U.S. secretary of the Army, 27th United States secretary of defense and Lt. Col (ret) Esper would not be using the term in any other than in the most general and vague way in such a definitive statement? Like I say, maybe you're right, but it doesn't sound like it, that's all. Is it possible to cite or link to "the powers granted by the President to the Secretary of Defense to deploy troops (which) are wide-ranging" as part of an answer to "How do the US President's and Secretary of Defense's power to deploy troops differ?" Can you name at least one difference?

Comment: Otherwise I'm not seeing an actual answer here yet.

Comment: How do the US President's and Secretary of Defense's power to deploy troops differ?"   The president derives his power from the constitution.  The Defense secretary derives his power from the President (and Congress).  THe defense secretary can be overruled by the president. The President can't be overruled by the Def. Sec.   I'm sorry that you don't see this as an answer, it is the best I can do, and well sourced in actual law.

Comment: So they don't differ in scope or capability? The Secretary of Defense has exactly the same power to deploy troops as the president? I haven't asked about the sources of power, I've asked about the powers themselves. Is there anything that one can do that the other can't? I am having hard time believing there isn't, but so far your answer doesn't address how the powers differ. If I present two batteries and ask how their powers differ, answering that one's power is derived from it's manufacturer in Japan and the other's power was instilled by a recharger in Belgium, it doesn't really answer...

Comment: But in practice the people receiving the orders are expecting to hear from the Sec Def, not POTUS.  It's not really any different from a CEO being able to direct say their IT staff to do something but that staff would in fact expect to hear from the CIO.  And the CEO not knowing exactly who to call to get something done while the CIO's job is to know the exact procedures relevant to their field.  So there is a difference, *in practice*, that is not of the same nature as considering solely the *legal* aspects.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That is until a CEO comes along that thinks it can do a better job than its CIO and starts calling people and ordering them around. Practices vary wildly often and the question wasn't asking how it is done in practice. In practice probably (hopefully) some experienced generals are doing the deploying and not the sec def. Sec def and president only decide to start the whole thing.

Comment: "So they don't differ in scope or capability?"  Yes they differ: The president derives his power from the constitution. The Defense secretary derives his power from the President (and Congress). THe defense secretary can be overruled by the president. The President can't be overruled by the Def. Sec. So the scope and capability of the Def Sec is entirely subordinate to that of the President.

Comment: @JamesK I see now that while you didn't mention it in a comment you've made an edit and added the last paragraph. The OP doesn't get notifications when answers are edited, so if you edit your answer in response to the OP's comment the only practical way they're going to know about it is if you ping them with a comment. I ask a lot of questions in a lot of sites, I can't possible click "follow" on all the answers to them. So the final paragraph is indeed an actual difference. *Thanks!*